# Passing a numeric argument through `\newcommand` or `\renewcommand` to a `calc` package command?

Tags: macros, calc

Consider the following MnotWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand{\scaleandcenter}[2]{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}}}}
\newcommand{\binscaled}[2]{\mathbin{\scaleandcenter{#1}{#2}}}
\newcommand{\smallbin}[1]{\binscaled{0.5}{#1}}

\newcommand{\setbinprecedence}[2]{\setlength{\medmuskip}{(1 + #1)*1mu plus (1 + #1)*1mu minus (1 + #1)*1mu} {#2}}

\let\origtimes\times
\renewcommand{\times}{\setbinprecedence{0}{\smallop{\origtimes}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        a\times b + c\times b = 0
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

It produces errors, because it doesn't like how I am using arguments in the arithmetic within the `\setlength` command. How do I properly pass an argument as a number for use within a `calc` package command?

Purpose: I would like to set up a kind of "visual precedence" style, where operands for my custom `\times` are tighter around it than the operands around the +, because `\times` should have "higher precedence" than +. Another way to say it: "visually" the operands around times should be grouped tightly around it, to pass on intuitively the notion that times should be performed first. So I was hoping to set custom `medmuskips` (including stretches and shrinks) depending on the precedence level of the operator.

Comment: the error is undefined command `\setvalue` simply because `\setvalue` has not been defined. the `calc` package is not involved in the error.

Comment: Even if the correct `\setlength` command worked (it doesn't with `mu` lengths with the `calc` package), this would not do: TeX uses a single value for `\medmuskip` in the whole formula, namely the one in force at the end of the formula. Besides, `\times` should be a `\mathbin`, not a `\mathop`.

Comment: apart from `\setvalue` not being defined, it is not clear what the intention of `\setbinprecedence` is, it makes a `{..}` group so will always be a mathord and the inner setting of `\mathop` will be lost.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I fixed that! You're right. I'd like to redefine the `\medmuskip` just for a particular command.

Comment: after the edit the error is now `Illegal unit of measure` but this is unrelated to passing arguments through `\newcommand` you can not use calc syntax with mu units, and in anycase changing `\medmuskip` at that point would have no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `calc` package doesn't work with muglue expressions. You might do *without* it by saying

```
\setlength{\medmuskip}{%
  \muexpr (1+#1)mu plus (1+#1)mu minus (1+#1)mu\relax
}
```

but this wouldn't work for the reason you're doing the setting in a group and making (the redefined) `\times` an ordinary atom.

However, there is a much stronger reason: TeX uses just one value of `\medmuskip` across a formula, namely the one that holds at the end of the formula.

Examples:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$a+b$

$a+b\medmuskip=30mu$

${\medmuskip=30mu a+b}$

\end{document}
```

You see that setting `\medmuskip` *after* the plus sign has been digested will result in enlarged space anyway. Similarly, setting the parameter in a group is of no consequence, because the value at the end of the formula will be the initial one.

[image]

If you want to make spaces tighter around a binary operator than the standard, remove a fraction of `\medmuskip`. For instance

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\tighttimes}{%
  \mspace{-\muexpr\medmuskip/2}
  \times
  \mspace{-\muexpr\medmuskip/2}
}
\begin{document}

$a+b\tighttimes c$

\medmuskip=30mu

$a+b\tighttimes c$

\end{document}
```

The second formula uses an exaggerated value of `\medmuskip` to better show the effect.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I would like to set up a kind of "visual precedence" style, where operands for my custom \times are tighter around it than the operands around the +, because \times should have "higher precedence" than +. Does that make sense? So I was hoping to set custom `medmuskips` (including stretches and shrinks) depending on the precedence level of the operator.