# How can I assign a specific `medmuskip`/`thickmuskip` for a particular binary op./rel., without affected the spacing for other operators?

Tags: math-mode, macros

I know that one can mess with `medmuskip` for binary operators, and `thickmuskip` for binary relations, to change the spacing around them: [How to change default for spacing around binary relations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55512/how-to-change-default-for-spacing-around-binary-relations)

However, LaTeX does not naturally associate a particular `medmuskip` with a particular operator, instead it associates it with all binary operators: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391879/49339

One could define custom spacing around an operator, by making LaTeX forget about any spacing rules it would normally use, and instead use your custom spacing: [How to redefine infix (binary, relational) operator spacing so that precedence can be communicated visually?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391885/how-to-redefine-infix-binary-relational-operator-spacing-so-that-precedence-c)

But the obvious disadvantage of this last solution is that it means you can no longer use the nice things LaTeX does in terms of figuring out how a particular character should be spaced: [How does TeX figure out whether a `-` should be typeset as unary, or binary?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392081/how-does-tex-figure-out-whether-a-should-be-typeset-as-unary-or-binary)

**The Question:** Is there any sort of middle ground? Can I have a symbol that is defined as a math binary operator (e.g. `\mathbin{\&}`) but have it use a custom `\medmuskip= Xmu plus Ymu minus Zmu`, which is different from the `medmuskip` of some other binary operator? In other words, instead of having one `medmuskip` for N operators, can you have N `medmuskips` for N operators?

My guess is: no, not unless you parse math expressions yourself, and then assign custom spacing. Here, PythonTeX and LuaTeX could come in useful (see the discussion here: [How does TeX figure out whether a `-` should be typeset as unary, or binary?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392081/how-does-tex-figure-out-whether-a-should-be-typeset-as-unary-or-binary)). However, I'd like to confirm this with the community (since it is much more experienced than I am) that this would not be possible with plain old LaTeX.

Comment: As I already told you, TeX uses a single value of `\medmuskip` (or of the other similar parameters) in a formula. If you do `\newcommand{\myand}{\mskip\muexpr-\medmuskip+Xmu plus Ymu minus Zmu\relax\mathbin{\&}\mskip\muexpr-\medmuskip+Xmu plus Ymu minus Zmu\relax}`, then `\myand` will do what you want, but only when in the context of a Bin atom; when used as a unary operator, this would break.

Comment: as @egreg said, I think this is just re-asking what has been answered previously.

Comment: @egreg I am finding though that applying that solution doesn't make the operator behave like a traditional `mathbin`: instead, it just sticks the specified spacing to the front, and the back, regardless of the placement of the operator. For instance: in an align operator, the custom operator per your suggestion do not align with the operator proper, but instead at the start of the "front" glue. Does that make sense?

Comment: @egreg sorry, that should read: "For instance, in an align environment, a custom operator defined per your answer does not align the operator with `&`, but instead the beginning of the whitespace with the `&`". Hopefully that makes more sense.

Comment: @user89 I didn't test this case, but there is no such thing as the whitespace with the `&`. Anyway, I don't think your idea of showing operator precedence via spacing is really viable.

Comment: @user89 yes that is to be expected you would have to use separate command names for the prefix and infix form, as suggested in previous questions.

Comment: @egreg Oh, the "beginning of the whitespace with the `&`" is ambiguous: I mean "the beginning of the whitespace of the custom operator is aligned with the `&`, rather than the body of the custom operator". Anyway, I expected this wouldn't really be possible, but I just wanted to run it by the community one last time...should I delete this question in your opinion?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Agreed, that's the most sensible way forward. However, unless I figure out a nice way to get "a compiled view" of the TeX I am working, there is something to be said about the loss of readability of TeX math when I am using commands like `\pl` for a `+`, etc. Eventually, it just all becomes a string of macros, which is difficult to reason with in the un-compiled form (I am not someone who writes everything out on paper first, beforing TeXing it). Overall, I think I ought to ditch the visual precedence idea, and stick to the same old.

Comment: you could use `\+` instead of `\pl`  if you don't need the other uses of those commands (and anyway you can save the old use as `\let\oldplus\+`)